# Systemd user unit that depends on system unit (sleep.target)

Tags: systemd

I was reading doc and it is still unclear for me, whether the following is possible to accomplish:

service defined in `~/.config/systemd/user/task.service` that depends on system `sleep.target` (`~/.config/systemd/user/sleep.target.wants/task.service`).

Now I expect `task.service` to start when I run `$ systemctl suspend`, however `task.service` is not started.

I'm running debian, with systemd version 208, `systemd --user` configured more or less as described on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User).

I wonder whether my scenario could be implemented with systemd at all, or are `--system` and `--user` completely isolated by design so that `--user` unit may not be a dependency of a `--system` unit.

In case it is possible, what might be the problem in my case?

Comment: [Similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/how-to-start-screen-locker-when-sleeping)

Answer (score 27):

From [systemd/User - Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)

> `systemd --user` runs as a separate process from the `systemd --system` process. User units can not reference or depend on system units.

There is a [feature request in the systemd GitHub repository](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3312) tracking this question.

Comment: This sucks. That's too bad.

Comment: I was just bitten by this. Thing is, `systemctl --user daemon-reload` doesn't report that there is a useless dependency in the user service file.

Answer (score 7):

You can also create a "proxy" for all your sleep/suspend targets between service and user instances.

Create this file on `/etc/systemd/system/suspend@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Call user's suspend target after system suspend
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --user --machine=%i@ start --wait suspend.target

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

And enable it by running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable suspend@youruser`.

Now create your user `suspend.target` at `~/.config/systemd/user/suspend.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=User level suspend target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
Wants=my-etc-service.service
```

Then add your services on the `Wants` list and make sure to run `systemctl --user daemon-reload`

Comment: Thanks ! I made it work with graphical.target flawlessly. Just don't forget to also enable your user service with `systemctl --user enable my-etc-service.service` of course ;)

Answer (score 5):

`systemd` user session services run in a completely separate instance of `systemd`, and doesn’t have any way to depend on system services directly.

There are other ways to accomplish what you want though. The cleanest would probably be to make whatever you want to run when the system is going to sleep hook into `logind`’s inhibitors and then run it as a background daemon.

A more general solution would be to have a daemon hooks into the `logind` inhibitors, (see [systemd-lock-handler](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/x11/systemd-lock-handler) and [xss-lock](https://bitbucket.org/raymonad/xss-lock),) and then when the system is going to sleep it will activate a user session target that you can order your services under.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the response from @kyrias, here's a way to create your own user level sleep.target:

~/.local/share/systemd/user/sleep.target

```
[Unit]
Description=User level sleep target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

~/.local/bin/watch_sleep

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',member=PrepareForSleep" | while read x; do
    case "$x" in
        *"boolean false"*) systemctl --user --no-block stop sleep.target;;
        *"boolean true"*) systemctl --user --no-block start sleep.target;;
    esac
done
```

~/.local/share/systemd/user/watch_sleep.service

```
[Unit]
Description=watch for sleep signal to start sleep.target

[Service]
ExecStart=%h/.local/bin/watch_sleep
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

See my blog post https://medium.com/@aiguofer/systemd-sleep-target-for-user-level-10eb003b3bfd

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve `sleep.target` (and a complementary `awake.target`) in userspace:

Create the following service template in `/etc/systemd/system/sleep@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=%I sleep hook
PartOf=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --user --machine=%i@ start sleep.target
ExecStop=/usr/bin/systemctl --user --machine=%i@ start awake.target

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Create an instance of it for your user (don't start it):

```
sudo systemctl enable sleep@$(whoami)
```

Now for the equivalent `sleep.target` for users:

```
[Unit]
Description=User-level Sleep Target
Conflicts=awake.target
```

And `awake.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=User-level Awake Target
Conflicts=sleep.target

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Enable with `systemctl --user enable awake.target` so that it starts at login

When either of these targets are reached, they stop the other target, thanks to the [`Conflicts`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) directive, which makes them mutually exclusive targets.

For my use-case, I actually found the `awake.target` to be more useful than the `sleep.target` because I could make some user services use the [`PartOf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=) directive to start and stop with it.

The only use-case I could think of that would benefit from the `sleep` target is if someone was trying to make use `systemd-inhibit` to do some last minute cleanup before the system goes to sleep. This would also mean delaying the actual sleep target until after the work is done.