# how to run a user script after systemd wakeup?

Tags: systemd, suspend

When my debian jessie desktop box wakes up from sleep (via the new shiny systemd) my mouse settings are returned to their defaults, having reset my customisation

```bash
xinput set-prop 12 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
```

which runs when I log in.

**how can I run an arbitrary user script on wakeup?** (assume that the user is the owner of the X session)

As far as I can recall, the following is the only customisation I've made of the `systemd` setup (yes, I know it's completely wrong because it doesn't work for arbitrary users, but I've not worked out how to do that yet... this is somewhat related)

**additionally, how can I run an arbitrary user script before wakeup, as the user who is currently using the X screen?**

`cat /etc/systemd/system/i3lock.service`

```
#systemctl enable i3lock.service

[Unit]
Description=i3lock
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=fommil
Type=forking
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/i3lock -c 000000

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/661747 It help me in my case which is different to yours. Maybe it can be useful to you.

Answer (score 15):

This answer is based on [askubuntu.com/a/661747/394818](https://askubuntu.com/a/661747/394818) (as also referred to in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152039/how-to-run-a-user-script-after-systemd-wakeup#comment629952_152039) by @sun-bear), [askubuntu.com/q/616272/394818](https://askubuntu.com/q/616272/394818) and [superuser.com/a/1269158/585953](https://superuser.com/a/1269158/585953).

### Using a system service:

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/my_user_script.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run my_user_script
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target


[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/my_user_script
#User=my_user_name
#Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

Remove suspend/hibernate/hybrid in case the service should only be executed after waking up from a specific type of sleep. In case the service needs to be run by a specific user, uncomment the `User=` and `Environment=` lines and replace the relevant user name.

Install the service file with:

```
sudo systemctl enable my_user_script
```

### Using a user service will not work:

In order to avoid setting a hard coded user name with `User=`, one could create the exact same service file at `~/.config/systemd/user/my_user_script.service` and activate with

```
systemctl --user enable my_user_script
```

However, that will not work. @grawity explains in more detail at [unix.stackexchange.com/a/174837/163108](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174837/163108) why that is:

> `sleep.target` is specific to system services. The reason is, `sleep.target` is not a magic target that automatically gets activated when going to sleep. It's just a regular target that *puts* the system to sleep – so the 'user' instances of course won't have an equivalent. (And unfortunately the 'user' instances currently have no way to depend on systemwide services.)

Comment: Note that according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#How_it_works user scripts belong in `~/.config/systemd/user/` and `~/.local/share/systemd/user/` should be used for units of packages that have been installed in the home directory.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about how to *automatically* map `User` and `Environment` to correct settings when system is used by multiple users (that is, Switch Account feature is used and multiple X sessions are running in different virtual terminals)? The value of `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables would be need to be set correctly depending on who has logged into which virtual terminal.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I think I may have an answer. However, we shouldn't do Q&A in comments. Please post your question and I'll attempt to answer.

Comment: @PhilHudson: good point – I created new question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716204/20336

Comment: For actually starting an *user* unit checkout my answer below.

Comment: I understand why WantedBy is needed, but why After? Why are both needed?

Answer (score 11):

I created a file in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` (you can call it e.g. `wakeup`):

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  post)
    /bin/runme
  ;;
esac
```

Then I set the executable permission bits.

```
# chmod +x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wakeup
```

The `post` is called on wakeup.

For further reading, look [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html).

Comment: This didn't work for me. Can you link to some documentation explaining how it's supposed to work?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. The context this script runs in is extremely limited, and does not run as the user who was active when the system went to sleep. So it does not get access to the display (which excludes most desktop utilities here), info/variables for the user who is logged in, or anything else related to the user's session who is currently logged in.  I need a script to run as the user who is logged in inside the context of the desktop session. I still haven't found anything to do this but I will update here if I do.

Comment: @theferrit32 you should be able change to your preferred user with the 'su' command from within your script.

Comment: If this didn't work for you, it's probably because you did not make the script executable.

Comment: If you want to run something as your user and have it affect the active X session you need to do something pretty roundabout, e.g., `sudo -u [username] env DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/runme` (provided root can run sudo without a password); if it requires D-Bus you might need to set the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable as well, which can be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Open this file:

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm
```

Contents:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in   
post)
    /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm resume
    ## Paste your command to run your script
    ;; 
esac
```

Your command will execute with **admin privileges**.

Comment: Ludicrously, I can't make this edit because "it's too small": There should be a newline after `;;` and `esac` should be on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a systemd unit file:

```
# /etc/sysstemd/system/awake.service
# ExecStart is executed on wake up from 'sleep' (suspend or hibernate).
[Unit]
WantedBy=sleep.target
After=systemd-suspend.service systemd-hybrid-sleep.service systemd-hibernate.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo awake from sleep' >> /tmp/awake.notes'
```

Often this will be used to restart a systemd service.

```
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart fancontrol
```

Answer (score 1):

All previous solutions do not provide a way to actually start a *user* unit after wakeup. You may want to use a user unit since you imported your environment variables there (e.g. with `dbus-update-activation-environment --all --systemd`).

I could only find an ugly solution to this problem which involves creating a system service that starts the user service:

Create the system service `/etc/systemd/system/afterwakeup@.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Run user unit of %i after wakeup.
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --user --machine=%i@ start --wait afterwakeup.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713646/454143.

And the user unit `~/.config/systemd/user/afterwakeup.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Runs after wakeup from suspend etc.

[Service]
ExecStart=<do anything you want here, dont forget to import your environment>
Type=oneshot
```

Now run `systemctl enable afterwakeup@<youruser>.service` and don't forget to import your user environment, e.g. in .xinitrc (`dbus-update-activation-environment --all --systemd`).