# How to run X programs automatically after wakeup from S3 sleep (suspend) or S4 sleep (hibernation)?

Tags: systemd, x11, xorg, hibernate, sleep

The existing question [how to run a user script after systemd wakeup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152039/20336) already has answers that allow running scripts after wakeup from sleep. However, the solutions provided to that question require hardcoding user.

**How to create a script that is automatically run by all currently logged graphical desktop sessions?** (That is, when fast user switching / "Switch Account" is used to have multiple desktops in parallel on different virtual terminals, the script should be run with each user with correct environment variable values for `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`.)

I'm personally using `lightdm` for creating new sessions / logging back to existing session but I'd prefer display manager independent solution.

Comment: On resume enumerate X.org logged in users and run whatever you need for them.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov if you add a high-level description of how to do that evaluation (eg parse the output of the "w" or "who" command), I'd say your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On resume you could enumerate logged in X.org users and run whatever you need for them. There are many solutions of how to get the list of currently logged in users but most of them are outdated and may not work in modern Linux distros, including: `w`, `who` and `last`, e.g. `w` and `who` return nothing on my Fedora 36 machine. `last` shows the last `reboot`:

```
last | head -1
reboot   system boot  5.19.4-az2       Sun Sep  4 01:56   still running
```

You can use them if they work for you.

Here's a contemporary method which must work as of September, 2022 (time stamping answers for Linux is always a good idea):

```bash
$ loginctl --no-legend list-sessions # or run it without any parameters
SESSION  UID USER   SEAT  TTY 
      2 1000 birdie seat0 tty7
```

Or `gdbus` if you're into programming:

```bash
$ gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1 --method org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.ListSessions
([('2', uint32 1000, 'birdie', 'seat0', objectpath '/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32')],)
```

Let's continue working with `loginctl`. You may need to know Xorg displays for the users, here's how you can do that:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

for session in `loginctl --no-legend list-sessions | awk '{print $1}'`; do
    echo -e "ID\tName\tDisplay"
    eval `loginctl show-session $session | egrep '^Display|^User|^Name'`
    echo -e "$User\t$Name\t$Display"
done

# output
ID  Name    Display
1000    birdie  :0
```

Instead of the `echo` statement you can run what you need, e.g.

```bash
    export XAUTHORITY="`getent passwd $Name | cut -f6 -d:`/.Xauthority"
    export DISPLAY=$Display
    command
```

Comment: Great answer! To avoid grepping, you could do something like `export DISPLAY="$(loginctl show-session $SESSIONID --value --property Display)"`

Comment: That eval statement exports three variables in a single command, so I thought it would be neat.

Comment: As this code is going to run as `root` if I'm understanding correctly, I'd avoid using `eval` for anything that can be affected by non-root users even in theory. If you're sure that all the output of `loginctl show-session` is trusted and cannot be afffected by the normal users, `eval` works fine here.

Comment: All these three variables are not controlled by the user but assigned to them, so I wouldn't worry.