# Systemd target units with same names but different contents

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, services

I am using Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon

```
$ systemctl --user get-default
default.target
$ ls -al /lib/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 16 Jan 10 05:56 /lib/systemd/system/default.target -> graphical.target
```

```
$ \cat /lib/systemd/system/default.target
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Graphical Interface
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=display-manager.service
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=multi-user.target rescue.service rescue.target display-manager.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

- I have `default.target` located in 2 different locations with different contents as follows:

```
$ \cat ~/.config/systemd/user/default.target
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Main User Target
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
After=basic.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

### Question

1. How to specify `/lib/systemd/system/default.target` inside a service unit file, for a user unit?
2. How to know which default target is used by a particular service unit file?
3. `systemctl --user get-default` refers to which of these default.target?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Systemd user unit that depends on system unit (sleep.target)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147904/systemd-user-unit-that-depends-on-system-unit-sleep-target)

Answer (score 1):

For knowing the current locations of a target, just query the status, e.g.:

```
systemctl --user status default.target

● default.target - Main User Target
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target; static)
[...]


systemctl status default.target
● graphical.target - Graphical Interface
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
[...]
```

The order of where units are searched is given [in the manuals](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#System%20Unit%20Search%20Path) (as system/user unit search path)

That means if I just create a dummy target in my local `.config`-dir and start it, it gets loaded first, as its position is higher in the search path:

```
$cat ~/.config/systemd/user/default.target

[Unit]
Description=just exists

$systemctl --user daemon-reload
$systemctl --user start default.target
$systemctl --user status default.target

● default.target - just exists
     Loaded: loaded (/home/felixjn/.config/systemd/user/default.target; static)
```

I.e. the unit serach path is just like the `$PATH` variable from shells: the first for a unit match will be taken.

The important part is to know, that user and system paths differ and do not overlap!

Comment: I am trying to start Firefox (user service file saved at ~/.config/systemd/user), if I write `WantedBy=default.target` and enable the service, which of these default target is this referring to? Basically its a GUI application so I want it to start after the GUI has loaded.

Comment: As said: it is a **user** service so it uses the **user** `default.target` -> `systemctl --user status default.target` .... should be `/usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target`

Comment: It is mentioned in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User that User units can not reference or depend on system units or units of other users. So, is /usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target, a user or a system unit file?

Comment: It is a user unit, as it is in the `/usr/lib/systemd/**user**/default.target`. But it is a system-wide one that would apply to all users - I assume that is source of your confusion?