# pm-suspend vs systemctl suspend in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, pm-utils

Currently, suspend does not work on my Thinkpad running ubuntu 22.04.

I installed pm-utils (`sudo apt install pm-utils`) and when I run

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

everything works fine.

What is the best way to change the default behaviour of the GUI suspend button and closing the lid to use pm-suspend instead of the systemctl suspend?

Comment: My brand new Dell Latitude 5570 laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 is refusing to suspend fully. I can wake it with any key, for instance, when it _should_ require pressing the power button to wake it up. I tried `sudo pm-suspend` to see if that would work instead, and, unfortunately, it won't. :(  It's even worse. Not only does the computer not fully suspend, but it also doesn't even lock the screen, so pressing any key wakes up the computer fully, and doesn't require a password to log back in. The Ubuntu 22.04 suspend option the power menu at least requires the password to get back in.

Comment: Update: my computer suspending to a shallow state that wakes up with a keypress is apparently expected. `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` shows only `[s2idle]`, meaning that my only sleep state possible on this machine is the shallow `s2idle` state. See: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt. I'm accustomed to the `deep` state being what happens when I sleep. That state *does* require pressing the power button to wake up.

Comment: This is a weird issue, I've been facing the same on a quite old laptop (ThinkPad T460p) that still worked pretty fine with 20.04 on that regards and that indeed suspends with `pm-suspend`. I ended up workarounding it for now via a script that just calls it on systemd suspend request (as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497106/168860).