# Start systemd user unit from system unit

Tags: linux, systemd

Let's say you have a systemd system unit:

```ini
[Unit]
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=<start-user-unit-here>

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

How can one start a user unit from this system unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Call user unit of %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --user --machine=%i@ start --wait <your-user-service-or-target>
```

Enable with `<system-unit-name>@<your-user>.service`.

I got this from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713646/454143) and just want to document. Credits to [Daniel Pereira](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/206680/daniel-pereira).